# I am unable to get rid of the borderline in the cell between line 6 and 7

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried to get rid of the the black line between line 6 and line 7, but unable to do so. [image]

Here is the file if anyone wants to try it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xmQMRGdsjLPdfAKfwo9Tkc8444iCyWDK/view?usp=sharing
edit: I realize the gif is too blurry, but since Imgur has a 10M limit, there is nothing I can do. I added a static picture. As you can see, there is no dividing line between line 6 andl line 7.

Another interesting new discovery is that the line seems to disapear when opened using Google sheet.
[image]
[image: a static picture]

Comment: Your image (animation) is of VERY low quality, showing just a few moving blobs. Look up "Clear all formatting" in a "dropdown menu" of the very rightmost part of the Ribbon menu ("home" section).  *No excel available to pinpoint it more*

Comment: Cannot open the Workbook after downloading it.

Comment: Would you please retry? @Lee

Answer (score 0):

The animation is horrendous, but (in my imagination?) it seems to me one line is missing. Obviously, we cannot read the line numbers, but one line seems missing.

The poster says the problem is between lines 6 and 7, directly, so that may mean I'm too imaginative, but something that would cause this is a line being used as a divider with a small height, say, 0.25. The poster should see that with the line numbers of course so... but in the animation, it seems at one point, just a shadow of a row number divider shows up below the first highlighted line and above the second highlighted line. So perhaps...

In this case, one would not guess it being meant as a divider, since it seems the first highlighted line might be the first line of data, not a header, but a manual method of hiding a row or column is to make the height/width neglible, but not zero, and perhaps...

It could be tested by bracketing using the first two rows the animation highlights and clicking to resize the rows. Make the value something like 12 (one can always Undo) and see if a whole new row pops in.

In the "old days" (so old, I use "old days" not "back in the day"... yikes) one would see this and someone would copy a top row to somewhere bringing along the "spare" row that was used as a border. Since we all gain separation height by simply increasing the row of interest's height nowadays, this ends up as a surprise now.

But then, he does call them line 6 and line 7 so... Still, there IS a missing row vs. expectations.